# Meaning of int in this expression

Tags: c, function, pointers

I could not understand what exactly does the innermost "int" mean in the following syntax.

```
int(*(*ptr (int))(void)
```

My understanding of this expression says that `ptr` is a function pointer takes nothing for its argument( from the void part of the expression) and returns an `int` (from the `int` in the beginning). But what does the `int` after `ptr` mean?

**Edit :** Apologies but the question in the question paper itself was misprinted. Here's the expression

```
int (*ptr (int))(void)
```

Comment: I had an example written up, but then you edited your question (in the grace period, so it's not in the edit history) and changed the syntax. Are you sure you have it right this time? `ptr` isn't a pointer here, so it seems likely to still be wrong.

Comment: Actually, the parentheses don't even match in the new version, so it's definitely wrong.

Comment: @user2357112 : I just copied the expression and it's exactly the way as in the question paper. But yes, Now I see that something is wrong with this question. The number of opening and closing brackets are not equal. What do you think of it?

Comment: I think it's wrong http://cdecl.org/

Comment: "... the question paper ..." So this is your homework?

Comment: @cartant No, it's not. I'm reading a sample papers for the interview of a software firm.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Bizarrely, cdecl.org seems to think the syntax is invalid if you use *this specific function name*, but not if you name it something like `x` or `f`. With a different name, it gives the correct interpretation. I think it interprets `ptr` in the input as an indication that you want English-to-C instead of C-to-English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the C standard, the `signal()` function has the rather complex signature:

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

The `signal()` function takes two arguments, an `int` and a pointer to a function that takes an `int` argument and returns `void`; it returns a pointer to a function that takes an `int` argument and returns `void` — the same type as its second argument.

This is more complex than your code, but it can be reduced to your example, which is:

```
int (*ptr(int))(void);
```

Working step by step:

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
void (*signal(int sig))(int);  // Remove second argument
void (*signal(int))(int);      // Remove argument name
int  (*signal(int))(int);      // Change return type
int  (*ptr(int))(int);         // Change name of function
int  (*ptr(int))(void);        // Remove argument of returned pointer to function
```

So, in context, it means that your statement is a declaration that `ptr` is a function that takes an `int` argument and returns a pointer to a function that takes no argument and returns an `int` value.  The implementation (definition) of the function will give an argument name to the inner `int`.

Example code — with `ptr` renamed to `function`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int counter(void) { static unsigned short val = 0; return ++val; }

static int (*function(int arg))(void)
{
    switch (arg)
    {
    case 0:
        return rand;
    default:
        return counter;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int (*func)(void);

    func = function(0);
    printf("F() = %5d\n", func());
    printf("F() = %5d\n", func());
    printf("F() = %5d\n", func());

    func = function(1);
    printf("F() = %5d\n", (*func)());
    printf("F() = %5d\n", (*func)());
    printf("F() = %5d\n", (*func)());

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
F() = 16807
F() = 282475249
F() = 1622650073
F() =     1
F() =     2
F() =     3
```

I'm assuming I could add `assert(sizeof(unsigned short) != sizeof(int));`.

Comment: You have an `int` where you should have a `void`.

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks.